# login in django using email or username (custom user model)

Tags: django, django-2.1, django-login, django-custom-user

i am new to the django. i want that user is able to login using username or email. i am using custom user model. register page is working properly but in login while submiting login data i am getting errors.

my code is not working. i do not know how to get it working properly. please if anyone can help to get in working properly.thanks

//views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import UserCreationForm,UserLoginForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth import login,get_user_model, logout,authenticate

# Create your views here.
def base(request):
    return render(request, 'articles/base.html')

def login(request,*args,**kwargs):
    form=UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        user_obj=form.cleaned_data.get('user_obj')
        print(user_obj)
        username = user_obj['query']
        password = user_obj['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            print("in login")
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            return render(request, 'login1.html',  {'form': form})
    return render(request, 'articles/login1.html',{'form':form})
```

//forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db.models import Q
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


User=get_user_model()
class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields=['username','email']

    def clean_password(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user

class UserLoginForm(forms.Form):
    query=forms.CharField(label='Username/Email')
    password=forms.CharField(label='Password',widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def clean(self,*args,**kwargs):
        query=self.cleaned_data.get('query')
        password=self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user_qs_final=User.objects.filter(
                Q(username__iexact=query)|
                Q(email__iexact=query)
            ).distinct()
        if not user_qs_final.exists() and user_qs_final!=1:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid credentials-user does not exits")
        user_obj=user_qs_final.first()
        if not user_obj.check_password(password):
            raise forms.ValidationError("credential are wrong")
        self.cleaned_data["user_obj"]=user_obj
        return super(UserLoginForm,self).clean(*args,**kwargs)
```

currently i m gettin this error

```
 TypeError: 'User' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: I don't understand how this doesn't crash in your `UserLoginForm`. In the clean method, you should always first call the super().clean() method to populate `cleaned_data`, then run your own validation. You do `cleaned_data = self().clean()` then manipulate `cleaned_data` and return `cleaned_data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with how you are accessing fields on your User object in the `login` method:

```
def login(request,*args,**kwargs):
    form=UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        user_obj=form.cleaned_data.get('user_obj')
        print(user_obj)
        # username = user_obj['query']
        # password = user_obj['password']
        username = user_obj.username
        password = user_obj.password
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            print("in login")
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            return render(request, 'login1.html',  {'form': form})
    return render(request, 'articles/login1.html',{'form':form})
```

When accessing the field values of a model, use `.` and not `[]`.

Comment: thanks for help..... but even after putting right credentials its redirect to login page not home page.... please can u help me with that                                                                         
            if user is not None:
            print("in login")
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')                                                                                i think this code is not woking